# display a notification when new record is inserted in the Database

Tags: php, mysql

working on a Hotel Booking Website.

There is one Master Table.I want to show a Notification when New record is inserted in Master Table.

Suppose I am on Dashboard of Admin Panel. So to check for the new entry in Master table, I am repeatedly calling a Ajax function. If I found a new entry , I am showing a Notification.

But Now I don't want to hit database all the time by using Ajax call, if there is no booking.

**I don't want to use AJAX.**

Is there any other way ?

So how can I, from a view page, keep watching Master table for new records and then show Notification for those values in the view?

Comment: Sounds like php socket...

Comment: It's either AJAX or websockets, take it or leave it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at a WebSocket solution. You can host your own with something like Slanger (https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger) or use a hosted service like Pusher (http://pusherapp.com). Both of these will let you set up realtime communication between your server and the client (web browser). You can add a hook in your code to send out a notification to your user/s every time a record is added.